# Tunneling socket could not be established in Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: botframework

I have found that I am no longer able to use Bot Framework Emulator on local (not using ngrok, not allowed at my company) after upgrading botbuilder packages to something higher than 4.7 (EDIT: I've now checked and the error appears to be introduced in `4.10`. It works fine at version `4.9` and keeping only the `botbuilder-testing` package at `4.9` doesn't help). Can anyone tell me what has changed that makes this not work, and if there is a way to continue testing locally? This is failing any time I use `await context.sendActivity` (I'm sure other things don't work as well, but that's as far as I can get). Here is how I set up the bot adapter. AppId and Password are **NULL** since I am running this locally and not using ngrok.

```js
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId, // this variable is null for local/emulator
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword // this variable is null for local/emulator
});
```

And here is the full error message. Yes, I know I'm not catching the error but I'm not going to put a try catch block for every sendActivity statement. The error details are no different.

```
(node:19488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR
 Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403
    at new RestError (C:\Users\e0077301\Documents\DevOps Projects\TRaCy nanorep\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:1403:28)
    at AxiosHttpClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\e0077301\Documents\DevOps Projects\TRaCy nanorep\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:2194:35)
    at step (C:\Users\e0077301\Documents\DevOps Projects\TRaCy nanorep\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:133:27)
    at Object.throw (C:\Users\e0077301\Documents\DevOps Projects\TRaCy nanorep\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:57)
    at rejected (C:\Users\e0077301\Documents\DevOps Projects\TRaCy nanorep\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:105:69)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at BotFrameworkAdapter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\e0077301\Documents\DevOps Projects\TRaCy nanorep\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:736:27)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (C:\Users\e0077301\Documents\DevOps Projects\TRaCy nanorep\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:13:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Here are the full index.js and package.json files:

index.js

```js
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

const path = require('path');
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });
const request = require('request-promise-native');

// Import and start application insights
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup(process.env.APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY).start();
const appInsightsClient = appInsights.defaultClient;

// Import required packages
const restify = require('restify');
const { CustomLogger } = require('./helpers/CustomLogger');

// Import required bot services. See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter, MemoryStorage, ConversationState, UserState, TranscriptLoggerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder');
const { BlobStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');

// This bot's main dialog.
const { DispatchBot } = require('./bots/dispatchBot');

// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about adapters.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {

    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    
    // Log to Application Insights
    appInsightsClient.trackTrace({
        message: `${error.name} - ${path.basename(__filename)}`,
        severity: 4,
        properties: {'error':error.message,'callStack':error.stack,'botName': process.env.BOTNAME}
    });

    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity(`Sorry, I've encountered an unexpected error and I had to cancel our last activity. If you continue to receive this error, please contact your support team.`);
    
    // Clear out state
    await conversationState.delete(context);
};



if (process.env.BOTNAME == 'Bot_Local') {
    // Memory storage - for development only
    console.log(`\nUsing MemoryStorage for state storage`);
    const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
    var conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
    var userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);
} else {
    // Blob storage - for production
    console.log(`\nUsing BlobStorage for state storage`);
    const blobStorage = new BlobStorage({
        containerName: 'bot-storage',
        storageAccountOrConnectionString: process.env.blobStorageServiceName,
        storageAccessKey: process.env.blobStorageAccessKey
    });
    var conversationState = new ConversationState(blobStorage);
    var userState = new UserState(blobStorage);
}

// Set up transcript logger
const transcriptLogger = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(new CustomLogger(appInsightsClient));
adapter.use(transcriptLogger);

// Pass in a logger to the bot.
//const logger = console;
const logger = appInsightsClient;

// Create the main dialog
let bot = new DispatchBot(conversationState, userState, logger);

// Create HTTP server
let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
    console.log(`\nSee https://aka.ms/connect-to-bot for more information`);
});
const restifyBodyParser = require('restify').plugins.bodyParser;
server.use(restifyBodyParser());

// Listen for incoming activities and route them to your bot main dialog.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // Route received a request to adapter for processing
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        // route to bot activity handler.
        await bot.run(turnContext);
    });
});

// Respond to pings
server.get('/api/ping', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Ping acknowledged');
});

// Listen for incoming notifications and send proactive messages to users.
server.post('/api/notify', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    try {
        const conversationReference = req.body.conversationReference;
        await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
            // If you encounter permission-related errors when sending this message, see
            // https://aka.ms/BotTrustServiceUrl
            await turnContext.sendActivity(req.body.message);
        });

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write('<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>');
        res.end();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Bad request');
        appInsightsClient.trackTrace({
            message: `${error.name} - ${path.basename(__filename)} /api/notify`,
            severity: 4,
            properties: {'error':error.message,'callStack':error.stack,'botName': process.env.BOTNAME}
        });

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.writeHead(400);
        res.write('<html><body><h1>Bad Request. Please ensure your message contains the conversation reference and message text.</h1></body></html>');
        res.end();
    }
});

server.post('/directline/token', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        var body = {User:{Id:req.body.userId}};
        const response = await request({
            url: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.DIRECTLINE_SECRET}`},
            json: body,
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        });
        const token = response.token;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write(token);
        res.end();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.write('Call to retrieve token from Direct Line failed');
        res.end();
    }
})
```

package.json (with botbuilder packages updated to latest. If I downgrade all of them to 4.7.0 it works)

```js
{
  "name": "core-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A bot that demonstrates core AI capabilities",
  "author": "Microsoft",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "nyc": {
    "exclude": [
      "test",
      "helpers/cardHelper.js"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index.js",
    "watch": "nodemon ./index.js",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test:dev": "mocha test/**/*test.js",
    "test": "nyc --reporter=text --reporter=cobertura  mocha test/**/*test.js --timeout 10000 --reporter mocha-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=./mocha-reporter-config.json",
    "test:inspect": "mocha test/**/*test.js --inspect-brk",
    "testList": "node ./node_modules/mocha-list-tests/mocha-list-tests.js test/"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/recognizers-text-data-types-timex-expression": "^1.1.4",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0",
    "applicationinsights": "^1.6.0",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",
    "botbuilder": "^4.12.0",
    "botbuilder-ai": "^4.12.0",
    "botbuilder-azure": "^4.12.0",
    "botbuilder-dialogs": "^4.12.0",
    "botbuilder-testing": "^4.12.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "mocha-list-tests": "^1.0.2",
    "nock": "^11.7.0",
    "remove-markdown": "^0.3.0",
    "restify": "^7.2.3",
    "turndown": "^5.0.3",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^5.0.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.23.1",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.1.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this or is it still an issue? Does the version of Emulator align with the BotBuilder package versions? It's worth noting that Emulator does use ngrok under the hood for port management. It doesn't make any calls so it _shouldn't_ pose a problem unless the app itself is blocked even from running on your machine. If it's not blocked, try installing ngrok and setting it up in Emulator's settings, and run again.

Comment: It is still an issue. The emulator version does NOT align (emulator version is 4.12, I have a variety of package versions including 4.5, 4.7, and latest which might be 4.12?). I can certainly try finding an old version of the emulator, but then why would it work with some package versions and not with others? ngrok is blocked by my organization, but I have never had an issue with local testing before, and it still works up to at least botbuilder package version 4.7.

Comment: I'm unable to repro the issue you are encountering. Are you able to edit your post to include some barebones code that repros the issue? I'm primarily interested in your "index.js" and "package.json" files (it looks like this is using the JS SDK, yes?).

Comment: Yes, js. Files have been added to the post.

Comment: After running through a few package versions, it seems `4.10` introduces the issue, and rolling back only `botbuilder-testing` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Does your bot use Direct Line ASE (application service extension) or DL Speech?

Comment: Right now it's not actually using either. That DirectLine token section though is to get the token for botframework-webchat. I just include that in all my bots in case I need it.

Comment: I found myself running into the odd issue when I had the newest version of Node installed. However, when I used the LTS version, those went away. Can you check that you don't have a version higher than LTS?

Comment: Definitely not newest. Running v10.15.0.

Comment: Hey Bill, sorry for the wait. When running locally, what are you passing in for the `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword`? If you aren't actually passing in values, the best option is to pass in a blank value or empty string. If you pass in `null` or `"null"`, this can potentially cause an issue with Emulator.

Comment: If that doesn't fix the issue, have you tried deleting the node_modules folder and doing a fresh install of the packages?

Comment: For local I had been sending undefined, as it was referencing an environmental variable that I don't have set on local. So I tried updating that to `process.env.microsoftAppID || ''` (and same for pw), which didn't fix the issue, nor did temporarily setting the value explicitly to an empty string. Lastly, I deleted the folder and reinstalled fresh but that didn't help either. I can only run `botframework-connector` at 4.9 and below to have it function. I have to believe it's something changed with requiring ngrok or creating the adaptor but I haven't found any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on windows machine, try setting this system environment variable – `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` instead of `HTTPS_PROXY`. This resolves emulator localhost issue running on http protocol to start communicating with the services that are on https. The proxy setting no longer works with botbuilder packages 4.10 and greater.

Comment: I don't know why v4.10 and above doesn't support proxy setting in .env, but removing the proxy setting and replacing it with the variable you suggested did fix the problem. I am now running on botbuilder packages 4.14 without issue!